# two levels menu and adding/removing class

Tags: jquery, nav

I need to develop a two/three levels navigation. When I clicked on any main item all the subs appears. I need that every main item I clicked its sub only appears and in the same time when I roll-out the sub, the class removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navigation__item").click(function() {
    $(".navigation__dropdown").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">

  <nav class="navigation-item">
    <a>first item</a>
    <div class="navigation__dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>link1:1</li>
        <li>link1:2</li>
        <li>link1:3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <nav class="navigation-item">
    <a>second item</a>
    <div class="navigation__dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>link2:1</li>
        <li>link2:2</li>
        <li>link2:3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <nav class="navigation-item">
    <a>third item</a>
    <div class="navigation__dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>link3:1</li>
        <li>link3:2</li>
        <li>link3:3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navigation-item a").click(function() {

       $("div.navigation__dropdown").hide();
       $(".navigation-item").removeClass("active");
       $(this).parent().find("div.navigation__dropdown").toggle();
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');

  });

  $(".navigation-item").on("mouseleave",function(){
      $(this).find(".navigation__dropdown").hide();
      $(this).removeClass("active");
  });

   $(".navigation-item").on("mouseover",function(){
      $(this).find(".navigation__dropdown").show();
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation__dropdown
{
  display:none;
}

.active
{
  background-color:lightyellow
}

.navigation-item a
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Working example here **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2udgsce/5/)**

Comment: Pawan, thank you sooo much it works! but only one something missing please if you can help in.. when i clicked on item the sub appears and its ok but when i clicked on another i want the previous one closed/ removed class and when i mouse out the sub i need it also disappeared

Comment: Welcome :) Updated the code! It should work for you now. Don't forget to mark the answer correct if it works for you :)

Comment: This part I didn't get `when i mouse out the sub i need it also disappeared` which menu should be disappeared, the submenu?

Comment: okay.. now i clicked the main item and the sub got display as block i need when i mouseout the sub got display:none or remove the active class.. forgive me if i can't mention it as clear

Comment: Pawan! can't thank you enough!!!! it works great.. buttttt :/ can we make the sub disappear when we clicked on another main item only?? what i mean is i clicked on first main item so the the first sub got displayed, i need it displayed until i pressed on another main item.. so sorry!

Comment: I think it was working in that way earlier. So you do not want the sub menu to get hidden when you leave mouse?

Comment: i needed it displayed as long as my mouse in the full nav area which is means it will disappeared in two cases, if i clicked on another main item and in this case the another sub will appear or i mouseout the nav block at all.

Comment: Kindly check the menu for this website to got my point www.alfaromeo.co.uk

Comment: I think what you are asking is the very first working code. Anyways, I have updated the code as well as fiddle, you can check on fiddle as well if it is what you want. 
Also, your this point `it will disappeared in two cases, if i clicked on another main item and in this case the another sub will appear` is irrelevant in the context since as soon as you will leave the main nav, it will be disappeared, so the div will be disappeared even before you click on any other navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navigation-item").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".navigation__dropdown").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you yezzz actually i edited in my file but still didn't work

Comment: you're welcome, I actually got called away, so I completed my code in a hurry